# how to count array length skip empty

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

i have data `numbers: []`

array contains

```
numbers: [{number: 5}, {number:}, {number:3}]
```

there is 3 object inside array
when i try `console.log(numbers.length)`

result `3` but i want `2` because 2nd object is empty

here is code what id try

```
computed: {
    total() {
      return this.numbers.length;
    },
  },
```

THank you

Comment: thats invalid `{number:}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to filter the numbers before return

```js
computed: {
  total() {
    return this.numbers.filter(({number}) => Boolean(number)).length;
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array filter to make new array with custom condition

```
computed: {
total() {
  return this.numbers.filter(el => el.number != null).length;
},
```

},